# Aurelia Features globalResources (jspm)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

Need some help with the feature and global resource stuff
using aurelia with jspm
in my src folder i have this structure

```
src/
|-- components/
|   |-- core/
|   |   |-- table/
```

in my main js i have .feature('components')

i have two index.js, one in components doing

```
export function configure(config) { 
    config.feature('core'); 
}
```

one in core doing

```
export function configure(config) { 
    config.globalResources([ './table' ]); 
}
```

i get `http://localhost:5000/core/index.js 404 (Not Found)` from system js
can you have sub-leveled features? or better yet can I have this

```
|-- src/
|-- components/
|   |-- core/
```

---

### Updates

I have managed to get something working, one point to make:

`core/index.js` should look like this:

```
export function configure(config) {
    config.globalResources('./table/table'); // I was missing the fact
    // I needed folder name AND js file name (without prefix)
}
```

Secondly it has to be this folder structure:

```
src/
|-- core/
|   |-- table/
```

It appears you can't have a feature nested in a feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a feature nested in a feature, you just need to provide the full path.

The `config` param of `configure(config)` is of type FrameworkConfiguration, and when registering features it "thinks" from the perspective of the src root.

Given this structure:

```
src/
|-- main.js
|-- components/
|   |-- index.js
|   |-- core/
|   |   |-- index.js
|   |   |-- table/
|   |   |   |-- index.js
|   |   |   |-- table.js
|   |   |   |-- table.html
```

You would need the following configure functions:

**src/main.js**

```
aurelia.use.feature('components');
```

**src/components/index.js**

```
export function configure(config) {
    let params = {}
    config.feature('components/core');
}
```

**src/components/core/index.js**

```
export function configure(config) {
    config.feature('components/core/table');
}
```

**src/components/core/table/index.js**

```
export function configure(config) {
    config.globalResources([ './table' ]);
}
```

You could make this a little more refactoring-proof by passing down the parent path from the parent, so that the child does not need to know its own absolute path, like so:

**src/main.js**

```
aurelia.use.feature('components', params => params.parent = 'components');
```

**src/components/index.js**

```
export function configure(config, configure) {
    let params = { parent: '.' };
    configure(params);
    config.feature(`${params.parent}/core`, params => params.parent = `${params.parent}/core`);
}
```

**src/components/core/index.js**

```
export function configure(config, configure) {
    let params = { parent: '.' };
    configure(params);
    config.feature(`${params.parent}/table`);
}
```

**src/components/core/table/index.js**

```
export function configure(config) {
    config.globalResources([ './table' ]);
}
```

The Aurelia team appears to be working on this also, but I don't know what the current status is: https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/376